# Passing a javascript variable to a jQuery plugin initilize function

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototypejs, owl-carousel

I'm using the jQuery plugin "Owl Carousel" and am coming up on a weird problem when I try to initialize the plugin with a javascript variable as an option value.

Basically I have the following:

```
// thumbnail_count is the number of images in the slider, 
// already calculated elsewhere

var thumbnail_breakpoints = '';
switch (thumbnail_count) {
    case 3:
        thumbnail_breakpoints = '[0, 1], [219, 2], [299, 3]';
        break;
    case 2:
        thumbnail_breakpoints = '[0, 1], [219, 2]';
        break;
    case 1:
        thumbnail_breakpoints = '[0, 1]';
        break;
}
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#itemslider-zoom').data('owlCarousel').reinit({
        itemsCustom: [thumbnail_breakpoints]
    });
});
```

This doesn't work and the value of itemCustom is not passed correctly to the reinit functon. However if I manually enter a value for itemCustom is works complete as desired. For two images e.g.

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#itemslider-zoom').data('owlCarousel').reinit({
        itemsCustom: [[0, 1], [219, 2]]
    });
});
```

Can anybody help me solve why this is? Using javascript debugging I can see that thumbnail_breakpoints is definitely getting set correctly. Also if I change the switch case statements so each one does the jQuery function call directly with the required values it works fine, but that is a massive duplication of code.

Thanks in advance for any help.

P.S. This is within prototypejs, hence why jQuery is called in no conflicts mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create 2-D array and pass it directly.

Use

```
var thumbnail_breakpoints = [];
switch (thumbnail_count) {
    case 3:
        thumbnail_breakpoints = [[0, 1], [219, 2], [299, 3]];
        break;
    case 2:
        thumbnail_breakpoints = [[0, 1], [219, 2]];
        break;
    case 1:
        thumbnail_breakpoints = [[0, 1]];
        break;
}
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#itemslider-zoom').data('owlCarousel').reinit({itemsCustom: thumbnail_breakpoints});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

itemsCustom should be an array of arrays but you are setting it to an array of strings:

```
itemsCustom: [thumbnail_breakpoints] = ['[0, 1], [219, 2]']
```

Change your code to set thumbnail_breakpoints as array or arrays:

```
var thumbnail_breakpoints = [];
switch (thumbnail_count) {
    case 3:
        thumbnail_breakpoints = [[0, 1], [219, 2], [299, 3]];
        break;
    case 2:
        thumbnail_breakpoints = [[0, 1], [219, 2]];
        break;
    case 1:
        thumbnail_breakpoints = [[0, 1]];
        break;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer and being so quick to do so too. In the end I chose Satpal's answer as the accepted answer as it also included the slight change needed to the jQuery function call.